# Facebook share_open_graph

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

I have Facebook sharing functionality on my website and I am trying to share dynamic data depending on a choice a user has submitted.  On desktop, things work fine but on mobile devices, I am running into issues particularly on Windows Mobile.  Any ideas how to sort?  My code is below:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',

    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            'og:url': [url],
            'og:title': [pageTitle],
            'og:description': [desc],
            'og:image': [shareImage]
        }
    }),
    display: 'dialog' // this is being ignored
}, function (response) {
    console.log('shared', response);
});
```

On an apple device, the popup is being blocked and not allowed to show unless user allows popups personally through their own settings.  Unfortunately I need to bypass this due to the nature of client base.

Thanks

Comment: How are you triggering this? Popups usually only get blocked, if they are not directly connected to a user interaction such as a click on a link/button ...

Comment: User is presented with an enter button, goes away and does necessary FB authentication.  If authenticated, it asked for an input and an image to select.  This information then goes into a DB.  All works fine up to this point.

User then can hit a share button which presents the FB share dialog box and this method calls the function above

Comment: Should add if not authenticated, it asks for permissions and so on which all works fine

Comment: And this gets called directly when the user clicks the button - no async methods or any callbacks involved, or sth. like this?

Comment: Maybe use the URL redirect version of the dialog instead? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect

Comment: URL redirection produces same issue - works on desktop but NOT on windows phone or iPhone.  Is there a specific issue with Windows phone and Facebook following changes released by Facebook in July 2017?  Before that date, other functionality on our site has been working but even that now has stopped.

Comment: Same issue how? So far you said the FB.ui popup being blocked was the problem ... so how can that be the same issue, if there isn’t even a popup involved any more?

Comment: It has been solved using the sharing url, instead of using window.open, using window.location.href works on all devices.